# How to mark AND as a query word not query operator in SOLR

Tags: solr

In my solr use case I don't have any stopwords. I found that AND is considered as a query operator though. I placed + in front of AND and now it is not considered as a word any more. Is that the right way of solving this or is there more preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz use double quotes to wrap it.

Example:

```
q=field:"AND"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your pipeline is not discarding AND as a stop-word. In Solr 4+, you can do it in the WebUI's Analysis section. It will show what happens with your text as it goes through the analyzers.